# Insert HTML through jQuery using .join() of an array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

The following script should insert the code that is set in an array into a specific div:

```js
$(this).on("click", '[data-action="toggle-cat-edit"]', function() {
  var catid = $(this).data("cate-id");
  var editorHTML = [
    "<div>",
    "<p>hello</p>",
    "</div>"
  ].join("\n");
  $('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).editorHTML;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit-category-tools-ID"></div>
```

I've tried through an alert: if the `cate-id` is set, the right div is gotten, and it works. But it doesn't include the array. Could someone help me on this? What have I done wrong?

Thanks in advance, I appreciate your effort.

Comment: use `.append(editorHTML)` or `.prepend(editorHTML)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).on("click", '[data-action="toggle-cat-edit"]', function() {
    var catid = $(this).data("cate-id");
    var editorHTML ="<div><p>hello</p></div>";
    $('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).append(editorHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

The line:

```
$('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).editorHTML;
```

isn't actually doing anything.

To replace the html in the element use:

```
$('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).html(editorHTML);
```

Or to append to the element:

```
$('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).append(editorHTML);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the HTML to the `.html` jQuery Function:

```
$('#edit-category-tools-' + catid).html(editorHTML);
```